# Какие отличия битовых и логических операторов в Java

Tags: java

Чем отличаются | и ||, & и &&.

Comment: Это же есть в любом учебнике по Java на первых страницах.

Comment: первае это битовые, вторые логические операторы. в чем вопрос?

Comment: @ДмитрийВасильев, не нужно менять вопрос полностью, когда уже есть ответы.

Comment: Понял, просто хотелось еще один вопрос задать, а время с текущего еще не истекло. Больше не буду

Comment: @олеггучанов, в чём ваша проблема? Не меняйте вопрос, задавайте новый. Что значило вчерашнее "больше не буду"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Операции &, | - побитовые операторы, а &&, || - логические.

Логические операторы неприменимы к нелогическим операндам, однако побитовые применимы как к любым "целочисленным"(`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`), так и между `boolean`.

```
1 && 2; // Ошибка
1 || 2; // Ошибка

System.out.printf("1 | 2 = %d\n", 1 | 2); // 3
System.out.printf("1 & 2 = %d\n", 1 & 2); // 0
System.out.printf("1 && 2 = %b\n", (1!=0) && (2!=0)); // true
```

Заметьте, что `1 & 2` будет 0, так как у операндов нет пересекающихся битов.
Из-за этого, битовые операторы нельзя использовать как проверку того, что оба оператора не нулевые

Битовые операции работают с bool операндами false/true, как c 0/1, результат bool.

```
System.out.printf("true | false = %b\n", true | false); // true
```

**Приоритеты:**

Приоритет битовых операций выше, чем у логических, от высшего к низшему:

> &, ^, |, &&, ||

```
System.out.printf("true | true && false  = %b\n", true | true && false); // false, т.е (true|true)&&false, а не true|(true&&false)
```

**Короткое замыкание:**

Логические операторы ленивы, они не продолжают вычислять очевидное выражение, например:

```
b = true || f(); // f не будет вызвана, потому что результат выражения не зависит от её результата
b = false && f(); // аналогично
```

Битовые операции этим свойством не обладают.

Comment: *"Из-за этого, битовые операторы нельзя использовать как (оба оператора не нулевые)"* - кажется, что-то потерялось. Кроме того, вы забыли рассказать про короткое замыкание.

Comment: а еще у них приоритет разный

Comment: О каком таком коротком замыкании речь, не знаком с этим термином, просветите, пожалуйста)

Comment: @vp_arth короткое замыкание - это особенность логических операторов, которые пропускают вычисление второго операнда если уже после первого все ясно.

Comment: @vp_arth никогда не видели проверок вида `foo != null && foo.bar == 42`?

Comment: Почему же, просто не слышал никогда, чтобы это называли коротким замыканием

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это обычно называют "сокращённым вычислением" или "ленивым вычислением". Про "короткое замыкание" слышу впервые.

Comment: @vp_arth, _"но побитовые применимы к любым"_ - что-то не то в этой фразе. К строкам они неприменимы, к объектам, тоже, да и к дробным числам... Какие-то нетакие эти все.

Comment: @Qwertiy ленивое вычисление - это совсем про другое. Сокращенное вычисление - да, так назвать можно, это синоним короткому замыканию.

Comment: Они тут официальный саппорт что ли устроили?

Answer (score 1):

Исходите из логики вашего метода. 
Допустим вы пишете метод для металлоискателя который должен проверить если ли у пассажира запрещенный предмет. Пассажир - принц эмиратов и у него 100 сумок. Нужно ли вашему методу перебирать все 100 сумок, тратить время процессора и время пользователя, когда уже в первой сумке он обнаружит топор?
Поэтому используете перегруженные И / ИЛИ.

Всегда лучше когда требуется кода **меньше**, и метод получается **проще**.

||,&& -  они будут побитовыми, если их применять к целочисленным операндам. А если у них операнды булевские - то операции логические.

Comment: `||,&& - они будут побитовыми` - наоборот же

Answer (score 0):

Там где два символа, это укороченный оператор, он если может по первому действию решить true, тогда дальше не проверяет, а там где 1 символ, проверяет в любом случае все выражение.

Comment: Кто ставит плюсы такому сумбурному ответу? Если бы я не знал о чем речь - я бы из таких "объяснений" ничего не понял...