# C# разница между & и &&

Tags: c#, операторы

Имеется следующий блок кода

```
static void main()
{
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
if(a==10 && b == 20)
{
 //что-то
}
else
{
//что - то
}
}
```

Но следующий пример работает аналогично

```
if(a==10 & b==20)
{
 //что-то
}
else
{
//что - то
}
```

Так же существуют подобдные операторы : |, ||, &,&&.
   
   В чём разница между ними?

Comment: `6 & 8` даст на выходе число `0`

Comment: @andreymal и про что это число мне говорит?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Какие отличия битовых и логических операторов в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743838) (В C# всё примерно то же самое)

Comment: @andreymal, при чем тут это? && (и ||) не вычисляют второй аргумент, если первого достаточно для получения результата, например, если первый даёт False, то результат логического И ясен без вычисления второго аргумента

Comment: @АндрейNOP при чём тут что?

Comment: Ну т.е. в шарпе & это в том числе и логический оператор, но в 99,99% стоит использовать именно &&

Comment: @АндрейNOP вот вместо комментария лучше напишите об этом ответ с пруфлинками :)

Comment: @andreymal, при том, что в вопросе про битовые операторы речи вообще не идёт, только про логические

Comment: Если топикстатер не слышал о битовой математике, то нужно просто рассказать, что есть огромная отрасль, где это всё нужно и востребовано, а пока он этого не знает - пусть пишет только && в тех самых 99% случаев и не парится. Поразрядными опеаторами если неправильно пользоваться - то можно влипнуть конкретно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP возможно, автор просто не подумал об этом, а потом однажды вместо случая подобного `int1 && int2` случайно напишет `int1 & int2` (потому что думал, что разницы нет) — и привет, выстрел в ногу

Comment: @andreymal, никакого выстрела в ногу, в C# нет проведения int в bool! И нет оператора && для int!

Comment: @АндрейNOP а, ну хорошо тогда. Это в ответе тоже упомяните для глупцов типа меня :)

Comment: Вот пруфы: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator и https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator но ответ не напишу, потому что уже сплю :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a == 10 && b == 20` - если результатом левой части выражения будет false, то `b == 20` вычисляться не будет

`a == 10 & b == 20` - будет вычислять оба выражения вне зависимости от результата левой части выражения.

Допустим a и b - строки, тогда:
`a != null && a.Equals(b)` - выполнится нормально
`a != null & a.Equals(b)` - получим `NullReferenceException` если `a == null`