# Для чего нужен логический оператор || и &&?

Tags: c++, логические-выражения

Для чего нужны эти операторы, если побитовые `|`, `&` справляются с этим?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 3;
    if ((a == 1) && (b == 3)) printf("True");
}
```

Равносилен по результату:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 3;
    if ((a == 1) & (b == 3)) printf("True");
}
```

Comment: Они справляются только с чистыми bool значениями. Разница в `if (1 & 6)` vs `if (1 && 6)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие отличия битовых и логических операторов в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743838/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577504/is-there-any-difference-between-and-with-bools

Comment: Коренное отличие в том, что для `&&` второй операнд (это ведь может быть и вызов функции!) вычисляется только если первый true, для `||` если первый false, а вот с `|` и `&` оба будут вычисляться

Comment: @vp_arth не только с "чистыми"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, «чистыми» я назвал {0, 1} Как только у нас есть значения не из этого множества, возникают проблемы =)

Comment: @vp_arth {0, X} тоже сойдет при X != 0

Comment: Но при X != 1, оно будет конфликтовать с нативными `a > b`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [&& и || и их братья & и | в разных ситуациях. Какие у них различия?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894602/%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Логические операторы работают по "короткой схеме", т.е. если результат вычисления становится известен заранее, то дальнейшее вычисление не производится.

В частности это широко используется в условных операторах, например:

```
if (ptr && ptr->func()) { ...
```

Если `ptr` нулевой, то вызов `ptr->func()` никогда не случится.

Побитовые операторы вычисляют оба своих операнда всегда, и могут работать только с целочисленными аргументами, в то время как логические работают с любыми, которые могут быть преобразованы неявно в булевы.

Comment: Как правильно читается ваш ник?

Comment: @Danis сложно сказать. Но на этот случай есть вот [такая ссылка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5878/176217) на Мете.